# Smarty - Too many conditions inside {IF} {/IF}

Tags: php, smarty, conditional-statements

I've got the following problem - I need to use condition {IF} {/IF} with many variables, but the whole site just goes blank when I put the code:

```
{if $product.id_category_default == 6 || $product.id_category_default == 9 || $product.id_category_default == 10 || $product.id_category_default == 11 || $product.id_category_default == 12 || $product.id_category_default == 13 || $product.id_category_default == 14 || $product.id_category_default == 8 || $product.id_category_default == 60 || $product.id_category_default == 35 || $product.id_category_default == 36 || $product.id_category_default == 37 || $product.id_category_default == 38 || $product.id_category_default == 39 || $product.id_category_default == 40 || $product.id_category_default == 41 || $product.id_category_default == 93 || $product.id_category_default == 31 || $product.id_category_default == 32 || $product.id_category_default == 33 || $product.id_category_default == 34 || $product.id_category_default == 94 || $product.id_category_default == 53 || $product.id_category_default == 54 || $product.id_category_default == 55 || $product.id_category_default == 56 || $product.id_category_default == 57 || $product.id_category_default == 58 || $product.id_category_default == 59 || $product.id_category_default == 95 || $product.id_category_default == 19 || $product.id_category_default == 20 || $product.id_category_default == 24 || $product.id_category_default == 21 || $product.id_category_default == 22 || $product.id_category_default == 23 || $product.id_category_default == 27 || $product.id_category_default == 28 || $product.id_category_default == 29 || $product.id_category_default == 30 || $product.id_category_default == 96 || $product.id_category_default == 97 || $product.id_category_default == 98 || $product.id_category_default == 99 || $product.id_category_default == 100 || $product.id_category_default == 51 || $product.id_category_default == 50 || $product.id_category_default == 52 || $product.id_category_default == 49 || $product.id_category_default == 101 || $product.id_category_default == 102}gardena{/if}
{if $product.id_category_default == 7 || $product.id_category_default == 15 || $product.id_category_default == 16 || $product.id_category_default == 17 || $product.id_category_default == 18 || $product.id_category_default == 61 || $product.id_category_default == 62 || $product.id_category_default == 63 || $product.id_category_default == 64 || $product.id_category_default == 65 || $product.id_category_default == 66 || $product.id_category_default == 67 || $product.id_category_default == 68 || $product.id_category_default == 69 || $product.id_category_default == 70 || $product.id_category_default == 71 || $product.id_category_default == 72 || $product.id_category_default == 73 || $product.id_category_default == 74 || $product.id_category_default == 75 || $product.id_category_default == 76 || $product.id_category_default == 77 || $product.id_category_default == 78 || $product.id_category_default == 79 || $product.id_category_default == 80 || $product.id_category_default == 81 || $product.id_category_default == 82 || $product.id_category_default == 83 || $product.id_category_default == 84 || $product.id_category_default == 85 || $product.id_category_default == 86 || $product.id_category_default == 87 || $product.id_category_default == 88 || $product.id_category_default == 89 || $product.id_category_default == 90 || $product.id_category_default == 91 || $product.id_category_default == 92}beam{/if}
```

Can it be caused by too many variables? Or maybe there is a way to shorten this code?

Comment: try OR instead of || and see if that helps

Comment: If the `if` checks are based around random list, then you can't shorten it. Only small changes like if `$product.id_category_default>9 || $product.id_category_default<14`.

Comment: a lot of those numbers are sequential. instead of testing `3,4,5,6,7` individually why not `if (x >= 3) && (x <= 7)` to reduce the number of tests?

Comment: another thing you could do is create a new variable in your php code ($prod_code or something) move all those conditions to your php code and set $prod_code to 1 or 2 based on the result. then your smarty condition is simply {if $prod_code == 1} {if $prod_code == 2}

Answer (score 1):

It is better IMHO to move the logic into the controller and build an displayproducts array there, and just use

```
{if $displayproducts.gardena}gardena{/if}
```

Smarty templates are meant to read by a web designer sometimes ..

Answer (score 0):

Even if this wasn't causing an error, and regardless of whether it is in the controller or the view, a long list of "magic numbers" like this should immediately be a bad "code smell". Anyone reading the code (including you!) won't know where this list originated or what it actually means, when to add or remove items from it, where else in the code needs to be kept in sync, etc etc.

You need to ask yourself what this list of IDs actually means, and why these particular categories act that way - they presumably have some property in common which should be given a descriptive name regardless of the effect it has on the front end.

If `id_category_default` refers to some ID in a database table, add a column to that table (e.g. `is_gardena`), and retrieve that along with the item data. You can then have a simple if statement in your Smarty code like `{if $product.category_is_gardena} ... {/if}`.

If that is not possible in your application, you should *at the very least* capture this logic into a single, well-named and commented function, containing an array of appropriate IDs and an explanation of what they refer to. You can then register that as a Smarty modifier and use something like `{if $product.id_category_default|is_gardena_category} ... {/if}`.

Answer (score -1):

Use array

```
$validValues = array("6", "7", "9", "15");
if(in_array($product.id_category_default, $validValues))
{
    // Do somthing
}
```

Comment: @RMcLeod php is where smarty gets its variables. this way would actually be better because you're sending fewer conditions to smarty and you're testing fewer conditions initially

Comment: @JeffHawthorne I'm fully aware of this, but the above won't work in a .tpl file unless wrapped in `{php}` tags which then defeats the purpose of smarty, the answer by @Adder is better

Comment: Adder's answer is simpler, but not better. in terms of long term maintenance, Hamed's answer is better because when a new product_id is added, the only modification required is a new number added to an array. handling the logic in the php file from which the tpl file is displayed is far better than creating a new if condition for every single product id

Comment: This answer would be fine if instead of "Use array" you said something like "Before rendering the template, use a PHP array to check the valid values", and instead of "Do something", you showed a variable being set that Smarty could use. As it is, this doesn't answer the question as you've moved from Smarty to PHP with no explanation.